# detect if JSON object has key with Yojson

Tags: ocaml

How can I check if a field exists in a JSON object using Yojson in OCaml? I need something like a `has_key` function like the following:

```
let () =
  let data = Yojson.Basic.from_string "{\"x\": 4}" in
  let has_x = has_key data "x" in
  let has_y = has_key data "y" in
  Printf.printf "has_x? %b, has_y? %b\n" has_x has_y (* true, false *)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Yojson.Basic.Util.member "x" data` returns `Null` if "x" is not a key of the Yojson data; or a `Assoc if "x" is a key.

you can define

```
  let has_key d k = not ((Yojson.Basic.Util.member k d) = `Null);;
```